# "which pyside-uic" gives a different file from what bash tries to execute

Tags: bash, unix, sh, pyside

So i've been trying to undo the braindamage that is my pyside installation, by completely removing all trace of it, and then reinstalling it. Surfice to say it's been a pain.

I'm currently encountering something really quite odd;

```bsh
$ which pyside-uic
~/pkg/pyside-sandbox/bin/pyside-uic
$ pyside-uic -o src/ui_mainWindow.py ui/mainWindow.ui
bash: /home/will/python-modules/bin/pyside-uic: No such file or directory
```

note that the `pyside-uic` it's trying to use when i run it is not the same as the one `which pyside-uic` returns.

What the hell is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BASH, the command to find what file will be executed isn't `which`, it's `type`. The `which` command may not give you the correct answer. On my system, it's a command in `/usr/bin/which`.

See if that helps.

Comment: To add to this, `bash` may have an old location for `pyside-uic` in its internal hash table; running `hash` would force it to check for matching entries in `PATH` directories again and update the hash table.

Comment: @sanmiguel exactly how I feel now!